# High precision integer math in C#?

Tags: c#, types

I have a very large number I need to calculate, and none of the inbuilt datatypes in C# can handle such a large number.

Basicly I want to solve this:

**Project Euler 16:**

> 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits
>   is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>
> What is the sum of the digits of the
>   number 2^1000?

I have already written the code, but, as said before, the number is too large for c# datatypes. The code has been tested and verified with small numbers (such as 2^15) and it works perfectly.

```
using System;

namespace _16_2E1000
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ulong sum = 0;
            ulong i = 1 << 1000;
            string s = i.ToString();
            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                sum += (ulong) Convert.ToInt64(c.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for correcting the title. I knew I was off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BigInteger from the J# classes.  [First question in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163696.aspx) tells you how.  It's a bit of pain b/c then you have to provide the [J# redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f72c74b3-ed0e-4af8-ae63-2f0e42501be1&displaylang=en) when you roll out tho.

Answer (score 3):

First to answerer you exact question, look for a `BigInt` or `BigNum` type

Second, from what I know of Project Euler, there will be a cool, tricky way to do it that is much easier.

As a first guess I'd compute the answerer for 2^1 -> 2^n (for whatever n you can get to work) and look for patterns. Also look for patterns in the sequences

```
V(0) = 2^p

V(n) = floor(V(n - 1) / 10)  
D(n) = V(n) % 10
```

Comment: There isn't currently a BigInteger type built into the .NET Framework, but there are implementations available out there (e.g. in the DLR).  But yes, your second point is obviously the real point of the problem!

Comment: Could you direct me to a slick implementation? :)
It seems silly to add hundreds of lines of code to be able to solve this problem.
Besides, it is nice to know of how to create a BigInt, so that I can use it in other future situations

Comment: Sorry don't known one off hand. Besides, should I really help you do something when I already think it is the wrong way to do it? <g/> (See part 2)

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is not a homework problem, but to get to the answer of 2^1000, you'll have to divide it into smaller chunks,

try something like,

2^1000 = 2 * 2^999 = 2^999 + 2^999 = 2^ 998 + 2^ 998  + 2^ 998 + 2^ 998

breaking into smaller bits till you get to solvable a problem,

complete solution to project Euler is on following links.

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/07/project-euler-problem-16-calculating.html 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/projecteuler

Comment: Well my first priority is to know what you can do if none of your inbuilt datatypes are big enough to handle your data.
My problem was just to illustrate an example where you might need something larger than the standard datatypes :) and no, it is not homeworks

Answer (score 3):

**It is not necessary to have `Big Integer` capabilities in order to solve this problem**.

*One could just use the property that*:

```
2^n = 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-1)
```

If Big Integer is really necessary for other tasks, **I have been using the BigInt class from F# in my C# programs** and am happy with it.

**The necessary steps**:

1. Install the [**F# CTP**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=61ad6924-93ad-48dc-8c67-60f7e7803d3c&displaylang=en)
2. In your C# (or other .NET language) application add a reference to the `FSharp.Core` dll.
3. Add: u`sing Microsoft.FSharp.Math;`
4. In the "Class View" window familiarize yourself with the members of the two classes: `BigInt` and `BigNum`

After executing these steps one is basically ready to use the `BigInt` class.

**One last hint**:

*To avoid declaring variables with improper names to hold constants that makes the code unreadable*, I am using a name that starts with `_` (underscore), followed by the integer constant. In this way one will have expressions like:

```
N = _2 * N;
```

clearly much more readable than:

```
N = Two * N;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a BigInteger (source code is available) that you can use; though, as already mentioned, there are more efficient ways to do this than brute force.

[BigInteger on codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/biginteger)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, while a biginteger utility might be of interest here, you don't need it, even for this. Yes, it looks like it does, but you don't. In fact, use of a biginteger form may even slow things down.

Since I don't want to solve the problem for you, I'll just suggest you think about this in a modular way.